# Image scale up and down flickering in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, animation, scale

I have an image im trying to create a pulsating movement with by scaling it up and down. [Example can been seen here in a Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nck011oa/5/)

Im using Chrome Version 53.0.2785.116 m (64-bit).

What I experience is that in Chrome the text/image flickers really bad. In Firefox it's really smooth and in IE it's also better.

The scaling is done with the TweenMax (GSAP) animation library and scales up and down by applying translate3D (scaling 90-100%) to the element like so:

```
translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px) scale(0.994027, 0.994027);
```

Formerly i've been able to fix flickering by applying the `backface-visibility: hidden;` fix, which is mentioned in multiple topics, but this time no luck.

Any Chrome fix/hack out there to make the scaling more smooth?